Rotating Projectile in Godot engine
I have this projectile code in Godot:
extends RigidBody2D

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    var angle = 60
    var power = 1500000
    
    var force = Vector2(-sin(angle) * power , cos(angle) * power)  # Push to the right

    apply_central_force(force)

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass

The projectile object is an 2d missile. But a projectile in real life rotates in mid air. How can I achieve that in Godot in order to get a more realistic projectile?

Rotation (spin) is around the flight path (one doesn't see much). A projectile otherwise "tumbles"; rotating around the center of mass. (i.e. before "rifled" weapons); and skewed based on windage and on which side it left the barrel.

Although it's a 2D game the projectile could be coming out of the screen (towards the player) at which point it would be a simple rotation, however assuming (as Gerry Schmitz has) that the projectile is flying across the screen, your best bet is probably just an animated sprite, showing the projectile at various aspects. Please provide more details in your question - if you need more help.

for example in real life when you throw a ball it rotates in the air, i want the same physics here

In real life when you drop a ball because of garvity and air resistance it rotates in air, how could i implement this rotation and physics?

apply_central_force() does not affect the rotation of your sprite. In your example, it appears you already have the angle at which you want your missile's sprite rotated so it's only a matter of adjusting the rotation property of your Sprite or AnimatedSprite
func _ready():
    var missile_sprite: Sprite2D = $MissileSprite # or whatever name you are using
    var angle = 60
    var power = 1500000
    
    var force = Vector2(-sin(angle) * power , cos(angle) * power)
    apply_central_force(force)

    var sprite_rotation_angle_radians = angle * (PI / 180)
    missile_sprite.rotation = sprite_rotation_angle_radians

Depending on the layout of the image used for your sprite, you may need to add a constant 90, 180, 270 degrees (pi / 2, pi, pi * 3/2 radians respectively) to sprite_rotation_angle_radians.
I'm not sure if this answers your question, but if you can provide more detail I'll be happy to help!

No, for example in real life when you throw a ball it rotates in the air, i want the same physics here

"When you throw a ball it rotates in the air". This statement isn't entirely true, if I throw a basketball, it will only rotate if I apply a 'spin' with my throw, or if some external force e.g. wind acts on the ball. To replicate this effect in your game will require you to consider these factors. How/Why is your body moving and how does this affect its rotation direction and angular speed? Try playing around with different values and methods of calculating angular velocity to find something that feels right

In real life when you drop a ball because of garvity and air resistance it rotates in air, how could i implement this rotation and physics?

@Miumen I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that. This is a question of physics and game design more than game development. Check out other games similar to yours and examine how they handle this behaviour. Fiddle with the values in your game to find the right balance between angular velocity and directional velocity, and don't be afraid to test 'extreme' values as you may learn something valuable. This is known as Extreme Tuning
